# Google Script Return Zip file doGet

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, download, google-sheets, zip

How can I create and download a zipped file on doGet on Google Apps Script?

Im trying this but it does not seem to work:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob("Testing zipped blob");   
    blob.setName("dir1/subdir1/values/strings.txt");
    var zipBlob = Utilities.zip([blob], "test.zip");
    return zipBlob;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `doGet` must return either an [HTMLOutput object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) or a [TextOutput object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service). Since a zip file is neither of these, what you are trying to do can't work.

As a workaround, use [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)  to return a page with a link to the file (which you save to Google Drive and make accessible with a link). References: [createFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename-content), [setSharing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setsharingaccesstype-permissiontype).